# Automatically Coping Columns between workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I need help creating a piece of code that will.

- Identify two separate workbooks: workbook1 (the source file) & workbook2 (active.workbook).
- take the column title in workbook1, find that column title in workbook 2 and copy the content of the column from workbook1 into workbook 2.
- move to the next column in workbook1 until its title is blank.

Comment: tried anything? where's your code? I could write this easily and I'm a newby in vba... ;)

Comment: Hi Kathara, sure ill update the original post with what i have so far... i am stuck on the bit that identifies the header and finds the same in the other workbook...

Comment: Just for the future: always post the code you have here on stackoverflow. Otherwise barely anyone will help... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me. Note the comments.

```
Sub copyA2B()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As String
Dim cel As Range
'assuming you don't know the source workbook name, looping through the workbooks, otherwise no loop needed
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
        wbSrc = wb.Name
        Exit For
    End If
Next
With Workbooks(wbSrc).ActiveSheet
    'assuming the column order is different between the two files, looping through the titles, otherwise no loop needed
    For Each cel In .Rows(1).Cells 'assuming the titles are in the first row in both workbooks
        If cel <> "" And cel(2) <> "" Then
            .Range(cel(2), cel(1).End(xlDown)).Copy Rows(1).Find(cel.Value)(2)
        End If
    Next
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi EranG thank you very much for putting me on the right path. i do know the workbooks (ThisWorkbook) where the code is, and the source is found through an update/prepare file userform. So i have the file name exactly.

Comment: You can copy this code to the destination file and run it from there even if you know the file names

Comment: If the solution works for you, ticking the answer is appreciated.

Comment: hey sorry, i was off work yesterday. ticked! thanks again EranG!